# https loading issue for jquery plugins

Tags: jquery

My site is a https secured. Recently I added one jquery plugin and also added google adsense plugin. After doing this when I opened my website in Chrome I found that in the URL there is a red cross of https:// instead of a normal green color one. After quite research I concluded its due to adding those external plugins.Because my SSL can only certify my site but not those external site. For eg. I use "**http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js**" plugin which is a external one. I created a local js file by copying the code form the above google library js ....and now if i load the new library js file  from my own wwwroot its working perfectly.......but I 100% feel that library files should be loaded from googleapis only as they get updated on regular basis with new fixes and so on .... so finally need advice whether my way of creating a local js out of googleapis is safe or is there any solution to fix this https issue of extrenal plugins?

Answer (score 2):

Use https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js instead.

`ajax.googleapis.com` supports fetching jQuery over the `https` protocol. Doing so will avoid browsers reporting that your site is less secure because it mixes secure and non-secure content.

Answer (score 1):

use without specifying the protocol. browser will determine witch one should prefer.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and use following code as backup plan

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/Scripts/jquery-1.4.0.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many CDN:s provide SSL access, for example you can load jquery from googleapis like this:

[https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js)

Answer (score 0):

You must include only contents from encrypted sources on an encrypted page. So include `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js` instead (mind the protocol).

Note that you won't get updates from Google's CDN anyway since you are specifying a version explicitly. Probably you would want to use `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js` instead (the `.0` is now gone).

I would recommend to specify the version of the library explicitly and fully nevertheless in order to prevent surprises. Assuming you test your site, you'll do this with a specific library version. Thus you know that everything works no matter if there are any bugs in the library. Note specifying the library's version fully gives you updates (that you probably won't need) at the price for having an update breaking your site.
It's better to load the updated version of the library locally in a testing instance of your site and once your tests complete successfully update the URL to the new library version.